# Can't get "Set /P fname=Input File Name:" to work with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here's my code:

```
SET /P fname=Input File Name:
for %%f in (%fname%) do "C:\ffmpeg" -i "%%f" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted/%%~nf_.mp4"
```

This batch file is used to convert 16x9 .mp4s into 4x3 .mp4s.  I could use `for %%f in (*.mp4) do`, but I don't want to convert every mp4 in the directory, just specific ones.

The issue I'm running into is that I can't use spaces in the input file name.

How do I alter the script to allow it to work with file names that have spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you seemed to understand that you needed quotes around paths and other variables in your script.  You think you might need quotes around `%fname%`.

Comment: There is big difference between this: `for %%f in (one two three.txt) do echo %%f` and `for %%f in ("one two three.txt") do echo %%f`. The first for outputs three lines to the screen whereas the second only outputs one line to the screen.

Comment: Adding quotations to the variable in parenthesis does not fix the issue.

Comment: Why bother with a `for` loop? Just ask for the name without the extension, and use ```"C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%fname%.mp4" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted/%fname%_.mp4"```. Or, tell them to input the full name of a `.mp4` file and just use ```"C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%fname%" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted/%fname:~,-4%_%fname:~-4%"```.

Comment: @Compo Thanks.  That second piece of code solved the issue.

Comment: It didn't work because you need to change this `"%%f"` to this `"%%~f"`

Comment: @Squashman Changing "%%f" to "%%~f" didn't work either. Compo had the right solution.

Comment: Compo's code is A solution.  If you ever delve into having file extensions that are bigger than 3 characters then you have to adjust the code.  If you use a FOR  command it takes care of removing the extension.  First two steps of debugging a batch file. 1) Turn ECHO on at the top of your batch file. 2) Open up a command prompt and execute the batch file from the cmd prompt.  This way you can see all the code execute and see what the values of the variables are. I find it hard to believe that the FOR command is not working. You have something incorrect with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of argument I am posting a solution using the `FOR` command. In my opinion this is the better solution as it removes the file extension regardless of length. I am just echoing the command as I do not have ffmpeg installed nor do I have any mp4 files on my computer.

```
@echo off
SET /P fname=Input File Name:
for %%f in ("%fname%") do echo "C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%~f" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted\%%~nf_.mp4"
```

Executing this code with echo off the output is as follows.

```
C:\BatchFiles\SO\78115464>so.bat
Input File Name:My File with spaces.mp4
"C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "My File with spaces.mp4" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted\My File with spaces_.mp4"
```

Executing it with ECHO ON shows you all the verbose output of the code.

```
C:\BatchFiles\SO\78115464>so.bat

C:\BatchFiles\SO\78115464>SET /P fname=Input File Name:
Input File Name:My File with spaces.mp4

C:\BatchFiles\SO\78115464>for %f in ("My File with spaces.mp4") do echo "C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~f" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted\%~nf_.mp4"

C:\BatchFiles\SO\78115464>echo "C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "My File with spaces.mp4" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted\My File with spaces_.mp4"
"C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "My File with spaces.mp4" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted\My File with spaces_.mp4"
```

And if you just wanted to drag and drop the file you want to convert onto the batch file your code could be as simple as this.

```
"C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~1" -aspect 720:540 -c copy "converted\%~n1_.mp4"
```

Comment: It should be mentioned however that the `set /p` input command is potentially very dangerous, and all input it receives should undergo robust verification before trying to use it. The most important rule of programming is that the end user may be incapable of following simple instructions, _(however well you think they've been explained)_, is capable of typographic mistakes, and may deliberately disobey your instructions. The drag and drop method is easily a better option, it almost eliminates those issues, _(they could drop a directory)_, but a dropped file will at least always exist.

Comment: No need to make this more complicated than it needs to be.  There are no end users.  Only I am using it.  I just wanted a simple way to change the display aspect ratio from 16x9 to 4x3.  That's all.  You've shown me how and all is good now.  So thanks!

Comment: @Squashman I think the drag and drop solution is probably best.  Thanks for explaining further!